# How big is the Settlers of Catan board?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, catan-seafarers

I'm considering buying a small table, and I want to be sure it'll support all the games I might want to play on it. Sadly, however, I don't have access to Settlers and all its expansion right now.

An article about [making a custom Catan board](http://www.tinysci.com/2010/07/04/the-settlers-of-catan-something-completely-different/) suggests that the base game should fit within 18" by 24", but that doesn't include the sea border or any of the expansions or extensions.

What is the physical size of the Settlers of Catan board when set up?

- ...with the 5-6 player extension?
- ...with the Seafarers expansion?

  - ...and the Seafarers 5-6 player extension?
- ...with the Cities & Knights expansion?

  - ...and the Cities & Knights 5-6 player extension?
- ...with the Traders & Barbarians expansion?

  - ...and the Traders & Barbarians 5-6 player extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roughly 15x16" for the base game.

roughly 15x20" for the 5-6p expansion.

About 17x28" for framed base game with C&K, and another 3.125" for 5-6p.

Seafarers can be considerably larger... up to 24x36"

I've not bothered with Traders and Barbarians, so I cannot speak to it.

Note that the travel version (which is base game only) fits nicely on an airline tray table.